# Why do I receive a Content-Security-Policy report from a simple message of "Hello World"?

Tags: html, security, firefox, browser, content-security-policy

I wanted to play around with Content-Security-Policy. I created the following program which

- Sets the Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only to default-src
- Simply prints "Hello World"
- Responds to Post (CSP reporting) by writing to the command line

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from io import BytesIO

class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.send_header("Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only", "default-src; report-uri /")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'Hello, world!')

    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        body = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        response = BytesIO()
        response.write(body)
        print(body)
        self.wfile.write(response.getvalue())

httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 8000), SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
print ("Serving on http://localhost:8000")
httpd.serve_forever()
```

I visit http://localhost:8000 in my browser, and this is what I get:

```
'{"csp-report":{"blocked-uri":"","document-uri":"http://localhost:8000/","line-number":1,"original-policy":"default-src \'none\'; report-uri http://localhost:8000/","referrer":"","script-sample":";(function installGlobalHook(window) {\\n ...","source-file":"http://localhost:8000/","violated-directive":"default-src"}}'
```

What is this? I tried this in incognito to make sure there were no extensions running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incognito doesn't stop add-ons after all. The violation was coming from react-developer tools. Disabling this fixed the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**default-src** is a directive which determines from where the resources can be loaded. Empty defaults to 'none', so that's why there is `"violated-directive":"default-src"` in the response. You should change it to 'self' in do_GET():

```
self.send_header("Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only", "default-src 'self'; report-uri /")
```

Comment: Thanks @Braca, but that's not it. I've tried that, and it reports the same error.

Comment: The only difference is that the 'original-policy' field of the report changes to 'default-src http://localhost:8000'